# Saving entity with existing children with CRUD Repository fails because of duplicate key

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

A `User` can have multiple `Authorities`. By default, when I create a new User I want to add him `ROLE_USER` authority.

This is the User entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User
{
    @Id    
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
      name = "UserAuthority",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "username"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "authority"))
    private List<Authority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
```

and Authority entity:

```
@Entity
public class Authority
{
    @Id
    private String authority;
```

I am using basic `UserRepository` and `AuthorityReposiroty` both extending `CrudRepository`.

This is method for registering new user:

```
public String register(User user)
{
    if (userRepository.findOne(user.getUsername()) != null)
    {
        return "User with given username already exists!";
    }
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    user.getAuthorities().add(authRepository.findOne("ROLE_USER"));
    userRepository.save(user);
    return "User successfully registered!";
}
```

When I try to register new user it fails with this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_c1gaghspdr9qx2yt45moye10y"
  Detail: Key (authority)=(ROLE_USER) already exists.
```

I can see in logs that Hibernate is trying to insert `ROLE_USER` authority which is not possible because it already exists, but I do not understand why. I haven't set cascade property on `@OneToMany`annotation.

How to I achieve what I want?

This is my configuration:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1206-jdbc42')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like your user already has the authority. Any reason you're using a list instead of a set, which handles uniqueness implicitly?

Comment: I've just tried with Set and the error stays the same. Problem is that Hibernate is trying to insert ROLE_USER authority. I can see this in logs:

Hibernate: insert into users (email, password, username) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into user_authority (username, authority) values (?, ?)

Comment: I just found out in pgAdmin that table I wanted to create (UserAuthority) is named "user_authority" and that it has constraint "UNIQUE(authority)"?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in relations. You have OneToMany - means that on other site is relation ManyToOne... If you used some Authority in one User you can't use this entity (object) for other user.

The solution of your issue is changing relation to `@ManyToMany` insted `@OneToMany` in User class. It's little streng, but in fact it is relation ManyToMany, because User can has many authorities and any athority can be used in many users.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Just one question related to naming: why is my table called 'user_authority' even though I set its name to 'UserAuthority' at @JoinTable?

Comment: this is depend of database dialect. Hibernate change table name and split words with '_' instead CamelCase. You can try by creating other entity with multi word name. For example in Oracle you will have table name all with small case like 'userauthority'

Comment: @matiska Specifically, look at Hibernate naming strategies.